# FTP: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client not connected

Tags: java, php, android, ftp, web-hosting

I trying to upload a pdf file using FTP from my android app and I still don't get the correct way of configure the ftp host, username and password. I user hostinger.

```
/*********  work only for Dedicated IP ***********/
static final String FTP_HOST= "ftp://ftp.BLABLA.xyz/";

/*********  FTP USERNAME ***********/
static final String FTP_USER = "*username*";

/*********  FTP PASSWORD ***********/
static final String FTP_PASS  ="*password*";
```

What have I tried so far:

1. I use the given ip address (185.28.20.76) in `FTP access` in C panel as FTP host, and for username and password I use what stated in `FTP access`. But when I enter the ip in browser, it is 404.
2. When I click `FTP account`, it said that I have no account. So I created one and use the information provided, like above. But still no luck.

Still new in using FTP for uploading and stuff, so which host name should I use actually?

Logcat:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at com.fyp.mycyberlaw.Lecturer.UploadNotesActivity.uploadFile(UploadNotesActivity.java:63)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client not connected
at com.fyp.mycyberlaw.Lecturer.UploadNotesActivity.uploadFile(UploadNotesActivity.java:73)
```

line 63: `client.connect(FTP_HOST,21);`

line 73: `client.disconnect(true);`